# Generate a number for a form selected state

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am working on a product configurator with interdependencies and many options. I'm looking for a solution how to restore the selected state for the form without saving data on the server.

My idea:

1. the customer makes his choice with checkboxes and radio button on
   the website (simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/benroe/6JRAm/5/)
2. customer print out the custom product with a short number at the
   bottom ("configuration number")
3. the employee in the store types in the "configuration number" on the
   website and same selected state (checkbox and radio button) are selected

But how to generate a short number for every possible unique states?

---

Simple example for the form:

```
<h1>Product Configurator</h1>
<form>
    <p>
            <label for="element_3">1: Size</label> <span><input id="element_3_1" name="element_3" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1"> <label class="choice" for="element_3_1">1m</label> <input id="element_3_2" name="element_3" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2"> <label class="choice" for="element_3_2">5m</label> <input id="element_3_3" name="element_3" class="element radio" type="radio" value="3"> <label class="choice" for="element_3_3">10m</label></span>
    </p>
        <p>
            <label for="element_1">2: Color</label> <span><input id="element_1_1" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1"> <label class="choice" for="element_1_1">Green</label> <input id="element_1_2" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2"> <label class="choice" for="element_1_2">Blue</label> <input id="element_1_3" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="3"> <label class="choice" for="element_1_3">Black</label></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="element_2">3: Extra</label> <span><input id="element_2_1" name="element_2_1" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1"> <label class="choice" for="element_2_1">Special 1</label> <input id="element_2_2" name="element_2_2" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1"> <label class="choice" for="element_2_2">Special 2</label></span>
        </p>
        <p><input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>

</form>
<p>Configuration Number: <input type="text"></p>
```

Comment: Why do you chose to not save data to the server? You could save a JSON representation of the state

Comment: After some time you have several hundreds of "configuration numbers" an it gets longer and longer. The number should unique for one specific selected state and not unique for one customer.

Comment: why not concatenate the values of each selected radio buttons in a specific sequence (sequence is important it should be same for every calculation). For your case the combinations will be like 111, 112, 113, 121 and so on. They will be always unique for combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? but adding the customer id:

http://jsfiddle.net/6JRAm/23/

```
$('#saveForm').click(function() {

var configuration='Clien_ID-' + $('input[type=radio]:checked,input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get().join('-');

alert(configuration);
});
```

Comment: Yes similar like that, but the configurator has 15 sections of input groups. With your solution the number is very long. Any idea?

Comment: If you want to store it to recover it later, you can do it in a cookie  or save it into a database. What is the purpose for saving it?

Comment: It's for an bike configurator. The customer can play with the options on the website and can see the price. If he is done, he goes to the shop and give the number the shop assistant. The shop assistant type in the number in the configurator and has the same configured bike. He can easily check if everything is correct or change some options.If every possible combination has it's own number it does not need any customer numbers or save data.